# I keep getting NullPointerException using a public array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I have two classes: `Main` and `Sub1`.

`anArray` is declared in `Sub1` as follows:

```
  public static int[] anArray;
  public Sub1 () {
      anArray = new int[15];
```

And then in `Sub1`, I try to set it:

```
  public static void methodOne() {
      anArray[0] = 5;
```

But when I try to run the code, I get a `NullPointerException`, and the message specifies:

```
Sub1.methodOne (Sub1.java:249)
```

Which refers to this code:

```
  anArray[0] = 5;
```

Why won't it let me mutate the array? If I comment that out, the error still occurs and just moves to another line where I tried to change the value of an index of the array.

Comment: Could you post your complete source code?

Answer (score 4):

`anArray` is a `static` field and trying to initialize it in a constructor of that class doesn't make sense. If you want it to be `static`, just initialize it at declaration:

```
public static int[] anArray = new int[15];
```

If you meant for `anArray` and `methodOne` to be instance members, then remove their `static` modifiers.

Either way I'd recommend you make the variable `anArray` `private` so that only publicly exposed methods can modify its contents and `final` so you don't accidentally re-assign it.

Answer (score 3):

Try initializing the array as follows,

```
public static int[] anArray = new int[15];
```

`static` variables aren't specific to an instance of the class, so it might not make sense to initialize the variable in the default constructor (although I'd have to see more of your code to know for certain if this is the case).

Answer (score 1):

You need to show more code, but your method, and the array, are static, and you're initializing the array in a constructor. My guess is that you're not calling the constructor anywhere.